# Bad operator (�): At line 1 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/ZYXEL-ES2108G-MIB.txt

Tags: snmp, mib

Bad operator (�): At line 1 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/ZYXEL-ES2108G-MIB.txt...while executing snmptranslate command m getting this error...What is the meaning of that???? any help

Answer (score 1):

Try adding -Pu

-P MIBOPTS            Toggle various defaults controlling MIB parsing:
                          u:  allow the use of underlines in MIB symbols

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your MIB is not formatted in SMI syntax properly. Try using `smilint` and rewrite your MIB to SMI conformance.